# Undefine index: session error

Tags: php, session

Whenever someone login `$_SESSION['semail'];` and `$_SESSION['username2']` are set. Whenever I go to profile page then I set session into a variable like `$email = $_SESSION['semail'];`
Then in error log an error is recorded as:

```
Undefined index: semail in /home/twekr/public_html/profile.php on line 11
```

My session start like this at top of page:

```
session_name('twekr');
session_start();
ob_start();
```

Here is the small part of script which is creating error:

```
 <?php 
 session_name('twekr');
 session_start();
 ob_start();
 if(!isset($_SESSION['semail']))
 {
 header("Location:https://www.twekr.com/");
 }
 if(isset($_GET['user']))
 {
 $id = $_GET['user'];
 $user = $_SESSION['semail'];
 $userid1 = $_SESSION['username2']; 
 include_once('config/db.php');
 include_once('frnds/functions.php');
 require('config/dbsettings.php');
 $userquery= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$user'";
 $userquery=$sp->query($userquery) or die($sp->error);
 $info=$userquery->fetch_object();
 $userr = $info->username;
```

This is the small part of login script where I set session:

```
  $_SESSION['username2'] = $get['username'];
  $_SESSION['semail'] = $uemail;
```

`$get` is performed here below:

```
 $check_login = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE  
 email ='$uemail' AND password ='$upass'");
 if(mysqli_num_rows($check_login) ==1) {

     $get = mysqli_fetch_array($check_login);
   $_SESSION['username2'] = $get['username'];
```

Comment: $get is from users database... i have updated the question

Comment: `$user = $_SESSION['semail'];` -- `$_SESSION['semail'] = $uemail;` look at those two very carefully. same for `WHERE email='$user'`

Comment: then what should i do? @Fred-ii-

Comment: use the same variable.

Comment: still same error @Fred-ii-